# Keep updating progressbar when view is destroyed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

In my Ionic 2 app, I use this function to download a video file and track its download progress:

```
download()
{
    this.progressbar=true;
    this.downloadbutton=false;
    this.fileTransfer.download('https://...videoURL....mp4', this.file.dataDirectory + 'path/to/downloads/test.mp4').then((entry) => {
        console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
        this.progressbar=false;
        this.startbutton=true;
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(error);
    });

    this.fileTransfer.onProgress(progressEvent => {
        if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
            console.log("### Download percentage ###: "+Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total)*100));
            this.setpercentage((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);
        } else {
        }
    });

}
```

Using `setpercentage`, I update a progressbar on the page

```
setpercentage(perc) {
        this.loadProgress = Math.round(perc);
        this.ref.detectChanges();
    }
```

This all works fine. When the user navigates away (back), the view is destroyed. The video keeps downloading (as it should), but when I navigate back to the page (while the video is still downloading), the progressbar isn't updated: the value stays at 0%.

How could I keep the progressbar updating, even when the view is destroyed?

Basically, I want to have this `page` to have the same functionality as a `tab`. When users navigate between different tabs, everything of the previous tab is remembered.

Any help is much appreciated!

Update:

Here's a bit more info how the app works:

When a user first navigates to the page, there's a button that says "Download movie". When the user clicks it, `download()` is called. `this.progressbar=true;` makes the progressbar appear, while `this.downloadbutton=false` makes the download button disappear. Once the download has finished, the progressbar disappears (`this.progressbar=false;`) and the "Play movie" button appears (`this.startbutton=true;`). The **problem** is that when the user clicks the download button, and then navigates away and comes back to this page, it seems like everything has been reset (although the movie did download), and the download button is shown again.

Answer (score 1):

When the view is destroyed it either goes to error or completion of your observable

```
 this.fileTransfer.download('https://...videoURL....mp4', 
     this.file.dataDirectory + 'path/to/downloads/test.mp4').then((entry) => {
        console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
        this.progressbar=false;
        this.startbutton=true;
    }, (error) => {
        this.progressbar=false; //////////////////////////////////
        console.log('error');
        console.log(error);
    });
```

The state of progressbar should be changed at all possible operations.

Also, when the view is destroyed

Implement `ngOnDestroy()` lifecycle hook to handle the same case

```
ngOnDestroy(){
      this.progressbar=false; ////////
}
```

Update 1 :

The syntax of the download method is as below

```
fileTransfer.download(
    sourceURL,
    targetURL,
    successcallback,
    errorCallBack,
    trustAllHosts,
    options)
```

source,target,successcallback, errorCallBack are mandatory parameters

**[Docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#download)**

Update the method based on the syntax.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. When I try to build to project with your suggested adjustments, I get a build error: `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

Comment: I didnt change anything in that method. how will you get this error then?

Comment: I've updated my question with the full build error. The error was to long to put in a response.

Comment: I'm using this plugin using Ionic Native. The implementation is slightly different: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/transfer/

Comment: i m sorry about the wrong syntax and updated answer will work

Comment: The error is gone now, but the issue isn't resolved. I've updated my question with some more detail about how the app works.